# Why do I get drastically different hash rates for different currencies

Tags: mining, hash, hashrate

I'm using MinerGate and when I try to mine Ethereum I get around 10KH/s but when I try to hash Monero I get only 200H/s. I know they would be different but 1000 times different? I'm using a CPU for both. Confused. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pretty sure the answer was already on here, but here is a new answer:

Ethereum and Monero use different ways of hashing to secure the blockchain (Ethash vs CryptoNote). The computational difficulty of hashing depends on the hardware and the algorithm itself. For example, imagine if I measured how many pairs of three-digit numbers you could add together using pen and paper in an hour. Compare that to how many pairs of three-digit numbers you could multiply together in the same amount of time. Harder algorithms, same computation hardware (your brain). Some hardware is more efficient at doing certain operations than others, too. This is usually measured in instructions per cycle. This is why, for example, a 386 computer running [can do more multiplications per second](http://zsmith.co/intel_m.html#mul) than a 286 running at the same number clock speed (MHz) and the reason why "more megahertz means faster" is referred to as the [megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth). See also [What aspect affects the GPU's mining speed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/what-aspect-affects-the-gpus-mining-speed)

Comment: Understood but 1000x? Wouldn't that depend mainly on the CPU/GPU i'm using?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to refer to "mainly" in general here; there is an interaction effect. Which algorithm is faster to compute can depend on the hardware (if you look up hardware benchmarks, which hardware is fastest sometimes depends on what software is running). Also, some hardware is just much faster than others. But yes - 1000x is not a surprising number. Easy to visualize: when encrypting a disk, some software can be configured to set the number of "rounds" the encryption is performed in; one can slow down the process by using 1000 rounds of encryption vs 1.

Comment: Ethash and CryptoNote are entirely different beasts. Your Adobe Photoshop takes 1000x times longer to start than your basic text editor. Both are simply examples of "starting a program". An algorithm that fits in your CPU cache is about 1000x faster than one that needs to use RAM. (all else equal) An algorithm that only needs RAM is 1000x faster than an SSD. And if it's too big for an SSD, a HDD is 100x slower than an SSD for random access.