# Optimizing hashrate for AMD radeon RX580

Tags: ether, mining, gpu

hi all i am new to mining , i bought 7 of the AMD radeon RX580 GPU 8 GB, to mine ethereum , i watched some tutorials on youtube about  how to optimize BIOS for the GPU .
I followed the tutoria and i pushed the HashRate/s from 19 MH/s to 21.461 MH/s
i was expecting to push it to 30 MH/s as the reviews are saying .

**i am using nanopool.org with asia server since i am in kuwait .**

**the miner i am using is Claymore**

what i want to know is:  why the hash rate dose not went to 30 MH/s for each even i did  the right steps for BIOS optimization.
dose it depend on the pool?
or i have to do more things

TECHPOWER-z : used it to save bios for recovery and for changing .

PolarisBIOSEdetor : to change the bios memory files after copying the data for 1.750 to 1.2000. and save it .

ATI-FLASH : to load the files that we changed in the previous step .

the tutorial i followed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKM60VVIfRg .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/at-what-point-are-mining-questions-off-topic

Comment: no it is not out of topic , you are just trying to look knowledgeable

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/what-aspect-affects-the-gpus-mining-speed is an on-topic-ish question.

Answer (score 1):

i'm also new at mining, i got MSI AMD RX 570 Gaming x 4GB version, with hynix memory.

i tested ETH mining with Claymore with stock bios, hashrate was around 18 Mh/s
so i used those steps to hit 28 MH/s now:

**

- **1. used Display Driver Uninstaller DDU to remove old drivers, reboot

  2. then install best driver for mining. reboot then editing bios memory
  3. timing, flashed modded bios. apply atikmdag-patcher, reboot
  4. got MSI afterburner to oc the GPU memory clock to 2000 MHz and core clock to 1200 Mhz , those settings are good in my opinion. you can find best settings for your GPU's.

**

you can test hashrate while mining while oc to increase Mh/s, till you get stable temp, power usage, best hashrate you can get 27-30 MH/s , no errors on gpu using HWiNFO64

my tips.... you should find best driver first, then use GPU-Z to see what memory type are your cards & find best timing bios settings, then flash one of your GPU & then Benchmark if all good, then flash the rest cards.

wish you best luck.

Comment: forget to tell you, i'm trying to test the ping of mining pool address, best results for me eu1 mining address as i'm located in Jordan, you can ping which one is better for you, asia or EU.