# Relation between GPU specifications and Hash-rate?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu, ethos, rig

I connected two following ethOS miners to Ethermine mining pool (https://ethermine.org).

You can see dashboard of my address here:
https://ethermine.org/miners/0x5Bf39b56e6e1698A01A5116e308e9CDf38787C7d/dashboard

While both miners have similar GPUs as follows:

**Miner 1: Worker name: 3b8f42**

[image: Miner_1]

**Miner 2: Worker name: 3b903c**

[image]

However, as you can see in my address dashboard ( [**Link to dashboard**](https://ethermine.org/miners/0x5Bf39b56e6e1698A01A5116e308e9CDf38787C7d/dashboard) ) in Worker table at the bottom of the page, **Miner_2** (with Worker name of **3b903c**) is always **significantly** **faster** than **Miner_1** (with Worker name of **3b8f42**). While Hash-rate of **3b903c** is around    **36.7 MH/s**, Hash-rate of **3b8f42** is around **18.1 MH/s** .

Another strange thing is that when Hash-rate of a miner is **increased**, Hash-rate of another miner is **decreased** ! such that always the average Hash-rate of both miners remains around **50 MH/s** !

**What is the reason?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just started using miner 2; if your local miner gives you a hash rate, you should believe that value over the dashboard for at least a few hours. There aren't enough data points for the dashboard to accurately compute approximate hash rate. I see each one has an average hash rate of around 35 MH/s right now. The increase/decrease thing just sounds like regression towards the mean. Eventually, I think the sum will settle to hover around 70 MH/s.

Comment: Thank you, Yes, now it has been changed. Would you please say how to calculate the average hash-rate (Mh/s) using GPU specifications mentioned in the question? And why the specifications of the GPU seems to be a CPU than GPU e.g. `Inter Core i3-4160 CPU @ 3.60 GHz` ? Thanks

Comment: You can’t really calculate the average hash rate of a GPU a priori (see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/what-aspect-affects-the-gpus-mining-speed). I don’t know why there’s no GPU stuff appearing; I suspect the 4x CPU lines are due to the four logical cores presented to your software.